# How would I specify a directory to run a PowerShell script that would edit file extensions?

Tags: powershell, directory, file-extension

I am new to PowerShell and new to IT. I've been asked by my boss to write a PowerShell script that will identify filenames that have no file extension and then change them to .PDF files. After doing some research online I've found a script that had a similar purpose and tried to tailor it to my needs:

```
   $proj_files = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq "."}
ForEach ($file in $proj_files) {
$filenew = $file.Name + ".pdf"
Rename-Item $file $filenew
}
```

My first question is does the logic in this script make sense? Is `"Extension -eq "."` the correct syntax to specify a filename with no extension? My other thought was to use `Extension -eq "null"` or something similar. If I do need to use a null value, what would that look like? My other question is how would I specify a given directory for this script to search through, or would I even need to? My thought here would be to specify the path under Get-ChildItem, like so: `$proj_files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\mthomas\Documents | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".'}` Does that seem correct? I am hesitant to test this out before getting a second opinion because I don't want to change every file extension on my computer or something stupid like that. Anyhow, thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere. Start small. Test. Observe results. Learn.

Comment: Totally agree with @Bill_Stewart. Small tip - Make a `Testing` folder in your system and add random files with different extensions. Test on them and then if you are satisfied with the results, try it on a bigger system such as a Production one, your computer etc. That is how we repro scenarios.

Comment: The script block in the Where-Object isn't neccessary for a simple comparison  `gci|? Extension -eq ""`  using some aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following to find files in a directory without an extension, and rename them to have a `PDF` extension:

```
$directory = "C:\Path\To\Directory"

Get-ChildItem -File $directory | Where-Object { -Not $_.Extension } | Foreach-Object {
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.Name).pdf"
}
```

## Let's break this down

### `$directory = "C:\Path\To\Directory"`

This is where we set the directory we want to locate files without extensions in. It doesn't have to be set as a static variable but since you are just getting your feet wet with Powershell this keeps it simple.

### `Get-ChildItem -File $directory`

`Get-ChildItem` is the cmdlet which is used to list directory contents (also aliased to `gci`, `ls`, and `dir`). `-File` tells it to only list files, and `$directory` references the directory we want to search from, which we set above. Note that `Get-ChildItem` might behave differently depending on the provider (for example, you can also use `Get-ChildItem` on a registry key), but if you are working with a filesystem path you do not need to worry about additional providers for this case.

### `|`

Passes the previous output down the pipeline. This is a common operator in Powershell, but basically you can string commands together using it. You can read more about the pipeline at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/understanding-the-windows-powershell-pipeline?view=powershell-6

### `Where-Object { -Not $_.Extension }`

`Where-Object` evaluates a condition on one or more items, and filters out items that do not meet the condition. Since `Get-ChildItem` can return one or more files, we use the `-Not` operator in the `ScriptBlock` (denoted by `{}` and make sure that there is no extension on the file. `$_`, or `$PSItem`, is a special variable used by the pipeline, in this case `$_` equals each item returned by `Get-ChildItem`. The `Extension` property exists on files returned by `Get-ChildItem`, and will be blank, or evaluated as `$False`. So filtering on `-Not $_.Extension` is the same as saying to only match objects that are missing a file extension. `Where-Object` can be read about in more detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6

### `Foreach-Object { SCRIPTBLOCK }`

Similar to `Where-Object`, but runs code for each object in the pipeline rather than evaluating and filtering out objects which don't match a condition. In this case, we pipe the each file without an extension to `Rename-Item`, which I'll break down further below. More information on `Foreach-Object` can be read about here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6

### `$_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.Name).pdf"`

Rename the current file in the `Foreach-Object` block to the new name with `.pdf` appended. The `"$( ... )"` is called a `sub-expression`, which is a string interpolation technique that lets you run a command within a string, and make its output part of the string. You could achieve the same effect by doing `$_ | Rename-Item -NewName ( $_.Name + ".pdf" )` which just adds a `.pdf` to the end of the current name.

## Summary

The pipeline is a very powerful tool in Powershell, and is key to writing efficient and less bloated scripts. It might seem complex at first, but the more you use it the less daunting it will seem. I highly suggest reading the additional documentation I linked to above as it should help fill in any gaps I may have missed in my explanations above.

To simplify the breakdown above, the command does this, in this order: Gets all files in the specified directory, selects only the files that do not have an extension, then renames each file found without an extension to have a `.pdf` at the end.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response. Much appreciated!

Comment: When I test this script, I get the following error for each file: Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'Settlement Agreement-pdf_0B-0AzQmMPj1YbW1RejlIZzVISm9NSGdEbmVpRUpSZldBYkY0' does not exist.

Comment: I changed it a bit - not sure why it would say the file it just found doesn't exist, but instead of using `-Path`, try piping the found file to `Rename-Item`. I changed the code sample above to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah so I tested piping the `$_` to rename and it works, but I figured out what was wrong with my old code. The file object actually gets ToString'd to the short name, not the full name (full path). So if you wanted to run it the previous way, just change the `-Path $_` argument to `-Path $_.FullName`.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in the script - the overall shape - makes understandable sense, but is not right for it to work as you intend.

Testing on my computer here:

```
new-item -ItemType File -Name 'test'

get-item test | format-list *

get-item test | foreach { $_.extension; $_.Extension.length; $_.extension.GetType().name }
```

a file with no extension shows up with an empty string (blank content, length 0, type `String`, so your `where-object { $_.Extension -eq "." }` needs to be looking for `""` instead of `"."`.

But:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '' }
```

shows me some folders as well, because they also have no extension in their name, so you might want `Get-ChildItem -File` to restrict it to just files.

> how would I specify a given directory for this script to search through, or would I even need to?

It would run in the current directory, whichever shows up in your prompt `PS C:\wherever>` so if you need it to run somewhere else, yes you'd need to change to that folder or specify in `get-childitem -LiteralPath 'c:\path\to\wherever'`. You haven't mentioned subfolders, if you need those included, `get-childitem -Recurse` switch as well.

Speaking of subfolders, your `$filenew = $file.Name + ".pdf"` only makes sense in the current directory, I think it would work better if you used the full filename including path, so they definitely get renamed in the same place they were found `$filenew = $file.FullName + ".pdf"`

> Is `"Extension -eq "."` the correct syntax to specify a filename with no extension?

Being careful here, what you wrote in your question was correct *syntax* but incorrect string content. What you've written here with quotes on the left of Extension is incorrect syntax.

> My other thought was to use Extension -eq "null" or something similar. If I do need to use a null value, what would that look like?

And being careful here, `"null"` is not a null value, it's a string containing the four letter word 'null'.

You don't need to use a null value here, normally if you do it looks like `$null`, but in this case you could use `where-object { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Extension) }` but there's no benefit to it, I think.

And, as a stylistic choice, both `""` and `''` are strings, but `""` can contain variables and sub-expressions, so if you have plain text it's a neat habit to use `''` for it because it makes it clear to the reader that you intend there to be nothing special happening in this string.

Then your code, with parameter names given, looks more like:

```
$proj_files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'C:\Users\mthomas\Documents' | 
                  Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.'}

foreach ($file in $proj_files)
{
    $filenew = $file.FullName + '.pdf'
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -NewName $filenew
}
```

If you want to see what it will do, use `-WhatIf` on the end of `Rename-Item`:

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $file.FullName -NewName $filenew -WhatIf
```

Then it won't make the changes, just tell you what it would do.

> I am hesitant to test this out before getting a second opinion because I don't want to change every file extension on my computer or something stupid like that

Sensible. But internet people are going to tell you to test their code before running it, because ultimately it's your responsibility to safeguard your files, rather than trust random code from the internet, so having test folders, having a spare machine, having a good backup, playing with PowerShell in pieces until you are happy with what they do, they're all good habits to get into as well.